# If nothing is found for field, create new field

Tags: php, mysql

PHP newbie here

I have a mysql table called "topics", and i'm pulling information from the table for a page based on a result from a form (in the URL through GET)

If the URL doesn't exist, i'd like to be able for the table to create a new entry with the topic name from the URL filled in

$topic_name would be what i'd be putting in the new topicname field

My code so far:

```
            $topic_name = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['t']));

//look for info
$topic_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topicname = '$topic_name' LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_numrows($topic_info)<=0) {
//insert record
$SQL='insert into topics (topicname) values ("'.$topic_name.'")';
mysql_query($SQL);
$t_desc='NEW TOPIC : '.$topic_name;
} 
else {
//do as normal (without unnessecary loop)
$g=mysql_fetch_array($topic_info);

$t_desc = $g['desc'];               
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I don't think i explained well, the result is from a GET from a form, so url.com/topic?=BLAH

blah would be the name of the field i'd want to create if it doesn't exist.

The table has an Auto incrementing 'ID' (primary key)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think i explained well, the result is from a GET from a form, so url.com/topic?=BLAH

blah would be the name of the field i'd want to create if it doesn't exist.

The table has an Auto incrementing 'ID' (primary key)

Comment: may be misleading. are you want to alter table with new field or want to add one more row if topic doesn't exist into table ??

Comment: If the topic doesn't exist I'd like to create it essentially, and then revisit the topic to retrieve the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correct :

```
$topic_name = (isset($_GET['t'])) ? strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['t'])) : '';

//look for info
$topic_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topicname = '$topic_name' LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($topic_info)<=0) {
    //insert record
    //UPDATE
    //$SQL='insert into topics (topicname) values ("'.$topic_name.'")';
    $SQL='insert into topics (topicname, `desc`) values '.
           '("'.$topic_name.'", "NEW TOPIC DESC")';
    mysql_query($SQL);
    $t_desc='NEW TOPIC : '.$topic_name;
} else {
    //do as normal (without unnessecary loop)
    $g=mysql_fetch_array($topic_info);
    $t_desc = $g['desc'];               
}
```

Comment: This seems to work and create, although when i go to revisit that URL, the stuff is blank, I've updated the original code

Comment: You may also have to check if the $_GET parameter is empty upon submission. Otherwise you run the risk of inserting empty values. Unless the table does not accept empty fields.

Comment: Ah, I see, if i (for example) want to add a view counter on the page, would that go inside the "else"? also, what would i go about the empty $_GET ? Thanks for your help on this

Comment: @davidkonrad mysql_numrows this is wrong.it should be mysql_num_rows()

Comment: Hmm, with this code it doesn't seem to be creating the new field, it will retrieve a field already made though

Comment: also desc is a reserved keyword. need to use backtick.isn't it ?

Comment: @mobile, added a ternary to check if t in the url is not set. If not, $topic_name is blank an you should theoretically (dont know your table) get an empty result set

Comment: I've copied the code and get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in topic.php on line 3

Your line 1

Comment: @mobile, forgot a ) in the ternary. Corrected. (also to GBD) it is (was) pseudocode written as example. My bad.

Comment: Great, seems to be working. So if I want to add code to a new topic, i put inside the "if" statement, and if it's revisiting the topic, i put inside the "else" statement?

Comment: Yes exactly! great it finally works :-) You may be most interested in a meaningfull desc, instead of "NEW TOPIC DESC"

Comment: Hmm, now suddenly i'm getting "Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in topic.php on line 3", have i done something wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are not connected to mysql. You need to be logged in to use mysql_real_escape_string, so maybe you now have your mysql_connect after the use of mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: Just found out why, I overwrote the wrong file, note to self, dont keep the same file names for the php function and the static page

Comment: If I just load the PHP file directly (without a topic) it tried to create it and now has a topicname of nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
$topic_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topicname = '$topic_name' LIMIT 1");

$count = mysql_num_rows($topic_info);

if($count <= 0){
  // do insert query
}
else {
// loop through you result and display record
  while($g = mysql_fetch_array($topic_info)){
    $t_desc = $g['desc'];               
  } 
}
```

Note: Better to use PDO or Mysqli lib for new development and prevent mysql injection attack